# JSON data to be set as per row in Google Sheet - getDataAsString

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the code below in apps script and I wanted to set it in my Google Sheet to be like per row.

```
var jsonFile = dataFiles.next();
var json = jsonFile.getBlob().getDataAsString();

sheet.getRange('A1').setValue(json);
```

I have tried this

```
var jsonFile = dataFiles.next();
var json = jsonFile.getBlob().getDataAsString();

sheet.getRange('A1').setValue(json);
```

this is what I'm expecting
[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNDRF.png)

but this is what's happening
[actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0cea.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that the entire JSON string is being set onto the single cell A1. If you want to convert the string onto individual cell outputs in Google Sheets, you can try this:

1. Starting from your current output, we can first split your JSON string using `.split("\n")`
2. We will then map the split JSON string, that is currently a 1D array value to a 2D array, to allow us to set it later on Google Sheets across multiple cells; for this, we will use `.map(x => [x])`
3. (Optional) During the splitting of the string, there are instances where the leading or trailing spaces would also be included; as such, you can use `.trim()` to remove them
4. We can now proceed to set the new JSON string array, but instead of using `.getRange("A1")` we will instead do `.getRange(1,1)` to indicate the coordinates of your starting range, which is the 1st row and 1st column of the spreadsheet
5. Additionally, as we will be setting values on multiple cells, we can add additional parameters to `getRange()` to include the number of rows and columns that will be included, so it would be `.getRange(1,1,numRows,1)` to include the range of included cells are multiple rows, but fixed to 1 column
6. Finally, we can use `.setValues(array)` to set the JSON string array values to each corresponding cell

**You may base your code from the sample script provided below:**

```
function splitString() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var json = `{
    "user": [
      {
        "name": "Test User"
      },
      {
        "name": "Diff User"
      },
    ],
    "body": [
      {
        "sender name": "Test User",
        "timestamp_ms": 1692160150774,
        "content": "test data from client"
      }
    ],
    "title": "Test User",
    "is_still_participant": false,
    "path": "inbox/Test_User1234",
    "magic_words": [

    ]
  }`;  // the sample JSON string, from your screenshot
  var jsonSplit = json.split("\n").map(x => [x.trim()]);
  // splits the values on your string per new line, then maps it to a 2D array
  // deleting any leading or trailing whitespaces
  ss.getRange(1, 1, jsonSplit.length, 1).setValues(jsonSplit);
  // the range will now be declared as row/column coordinates
  // then set the values of the JSON string array in their individual cells
}
```

**You may also click on the following links for your reference:**

- [split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)
- [map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
- [trim()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp)
- [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

Comment: OH MY! I've applied it on my end and the output shows the same thing as the expectation! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I will look more on those links for my studies :)